# How do I skip a loop with pdb?

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

How can I skip over a loop using `pdb.set_trace()`?

For example,

```
pdb.set_trace()
for i in range(5):
     print(i)

print('Done!')
```

`pdb` prompts before the loop. I input a command.  All 1-5 values are returned and then I'd like to be prompted with `pdb` again before the `print('Done!')` executes.

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Try the [`until`](https://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-until) statement.

Go to the last line of the loop (with `next` or `n`) and then use `until` or `unt`. This will take you to the next line, right after the loop.

https://pymotw.com/3/pdb/index.html has a good explanation

Comment: From the article: go to the last line of the for loop by using `n`, and then type `until`. This will go until at least that current line is exceeded.

Comment: Works with list comprehensions too. You don't have to care about the last line.

Comment: What would you do, if going to the last line of the loop is cumbersome? Is there really no equivalent to `f` used by R's `debug` function which "finishes execution of the current loop or function" (https://adv-r.hadley.nz/debugging.html)?

Comment: Using `until` (or its short form `unt`) without arguments will always go down a line (unless you hit a return statement), so you can also just use it a bunch of times instead of `n`.

Comment: It does not work with `breakpoint()` set in the loop in `python 3`. The `VB Editor` can accept breakpoints 'on the fly', but this is most likely not the case with `pdb`.

Comment: For me `until` does do the job as described in `python3` when stopped by a `breakpoint()`.

Answer (score 6):

You should set a breakpoint after the loop ("break main.py:4" presuming the above lines are in a file called main.py) and then continue ("c").

Answer (score 3):

In the link mentioned by the accepted answer (https://pymotw.com/3/pdb/), I found this section somewhat more helpful:

> To let execution run until a specific line, pass the line number to
>   the until command.

Here's an example of how that can work re: loops:

[image]

[image]

[image]

It spares you from two things: having to create extra breakpoints, and having to navigate to the end of a loop (especially when you might have already iterated such that you wouldn't be able to without re-running the debugger).

Here's the Python docs on [`until`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html?highlight=until#pdbcommand-until). Btw I'm using [`pdb++`](https://github.com/pdbpp/pdbpp) as a drop-in for the standard debugger (hence the formatting) but `until` works the same in both.

Answer (score 1):

You can set another breakpoint after the loop and jump to it (when debugging) with `c`:

```
pdb.set_trace()
for i in range(5):
    print(i)

pdb.set_trace()
print('Done!')
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `tbreak <line number after loop>`.  `tbreak` is a temporary breakpoint that is removed when first hit.

Answer (score -19):

If I understood this correctly.

One possible way of doing this would be:

Once you get you `pdb` prompt . Just hit `n` (next) 10 times to exit the loop.

However, I am not aware of a way to exit a loop in `pdb`.

You could use `r` to exit a function though.

Comment: And what if the loop is 10000000? Your answer is very obvious.

Comment: In that case, s/he would likely vectorize it:)